# Split a string of length nvarchar(120) without breaking words in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in a same database.

Table1, **New_Company_Data** it has column "Company_Name" nvarchar(120) which contains name of companies.

and Table2, **Old_Company_data** it has 3 column  "Name1" nvarchar(40), "Name2" nvarchar(40) and "Name3" nvarchar(40).

I want to copy the data from table **New_Company_Data** to the table **Old_Company_Data** but before this I have to split the companies name which are in column "Company_Name". I tried to split it but its breaking the words.

How can I split the data in "Company_Name" field with out breaking the words in following way:

IF company name is <=40 then don't split.

IF company name is >40 and <=80 then split it in two parts without breaking the words.

IF company name is >80 and <=120 then split it in three parts without breaking the words.

I am using following code but its not generating the results properly. E.g in the below code i am getting string2 as "ik u." But here I want to get next 40 characters.

```
declare @strs nvarchar(120)

set @strs = 'AlufinishGesellschaftfür Verfahrenstechnik u. zur 

Metalloberflächenbehandlung mbH & C' --40

declare @lon int
declare @palabras int
declare @contador int
declare @posicion int
declare @string1 nvarchar(40)
declare @string2 nvarchar(40)
declare @string3 nvarchar(40)

--wordcount
set @palabras = LEN(@strs)-LEN(replace(@strs, ' ', ''))+1 --3
--words per batch

if (LEN(@strs)<=40) set @lon = @palabras
if (LEN(@strs)>40 AND LEN(@strs)<=80) set @lon = @palabras/2 --3 
if (LEN(@strs)>80 AND LEN(@strs)<=120) set @lon = @palabras/3

--set @lon = @palabras/3
set @contador = 1
set @posicion = 0
while @contador <= @lon
begin
-- search for the first batch
    set @posicion = CHARINDEX(' ',@strs,@posicion+1)-- here it will found 1st space
    set @contador = @contador+1
end 
set @string1 = Left(@strs, @posicion)

set @strs = replace(@strs, @string1, '')

set @contador = 1
set @posicion = 0
while @contador <= @lon
begin
-- search for the second batch
    set @posicion = CHARINDEX(' ',@strs,@posicion+1)
    set @contador = @contador+1
end 
set @string2 = LEFT(@strs, @posicion)
set @string3 = replace(@strs, @string2, '')

--use test
--update company_backup

--set company1=@string1,company2=@string3 where id=12
select @string1 as string1, @string2 as string2, @string3 as string3
```

Comment: This is not McDonalds, you don't order stuff here. We can assist you resolve your problems, but first show us what you have tried.

Comment: Yes I have written a code but its too big to write here i mean greater than 600 characters. OR may be I can write that code in my question. Its my first day of joining Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the following function:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].WordWrap
(
    @WrapAt int,
    @Text nvarchar(1024)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(1024)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @ReturnValue nvarchar(1024);--the string to be passed back
    declare @Snip int;-- the length to snip to the last space before the wrapap value
    declare @Block int;-- the block number of the piece in the return string
    set @Block=1;-- initialise the block number
    set @Text=ltrim(rtrim(@Text));-- clean up the input string
    while charindex('  ',@Text)>0 begin -- if there are any double spaces
        set @Text=REPLACE(@Text,'  ',' '); -- replace them with single spaces
    end
    if (@Text is null or DATALENGTH(@Text)<=@WrapAt) begin -- if the input string is null or short enough for 1 block
        set @ReturnValue='<1>'+@Text+'</1>';-- load it into the return value and we're done
    end else begin -- otherwise we have some work to do
        set @ReturnValue='' -- so let's initialise the return value
        while DATALENGTH(@Text)>0 begin -- and keep going until we have finished
            -- if the character after the wrapat is a space or there is a space anywhere before the wrapat
            if SUBSTRING(@Text,@WrapAt+1,1)=' ' or CHARINDEX(' ',left(@Text,@WrapAt))>0 begin
                if SUBSTRING(@Text,@WrapAt+1,1)=' ' begin -- if the character after the wrapat is a space
                    set @Snip=@WrapAt-- we can snip to the wrapat
                end else begin
                    --otherwise we have to snip to the last space before the wrapat
                    set @Snip=@WrapAt-charindex(' ',reverse(left(@text,@WrapAt)));
                end
                -- now we can load the return value with snipped text as the current block
                set @ReturnValue+='<'+CONVERT(varchar,@Block)+'>'+left(@Text,@Snip)+'</'+CONVERT(varchar,@Block)+'>';
                -- and leave just what's left to process, by jumping past the space (@Snip+2)
                set @Text=SUBSTRING(@Text,@Snip+2,1024);
            end else begin-- otherwise we have no space to split to - so we can only cut the string at wrapat
                -- so we load the return value with the left hand wrapat characters as the current block
                set @ReturnValue+='<'+CONVERT(varchar,@Block)+'>'+LEFT(@Text,@WrapAt)+'</'+CONVERT(varchar,@Block)+'>';
                -- and leave just what's left to process, by jumping past the wrapat (@WrapAp+1)
                set @Text=SUBSTRING(@Text,@WrapAt+1,1024);
            end
        set @Block+=1-- increment the block number in case we still have more work to do
        end
    end
    RETURN @ReturnValue;
END
GO
```

and your table is loaded with the following test data:-

```
create table New_Company_Data (
    Company_name varchar(120)
);
go
insert into New_Company_Data values (null);
insert into New_Company_Data values ('');
insert into New_Company_Data values ('   abc   abc    abc      abc');
insert into New_Company_Data values ('a');
insert into New_Company_Data select REPLICATE('a',40)+REPLICATE('b',40)+REPLICATE('c',40)
insert into New_Company_Data values ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vehicula, quam non lobortis molestie, purus dui porta sed.');
go
select dbo.WordWrap(40,n.Company_name)
from New_Company_Data n
```

you get the following returned:-

```
NULL
<1></1>
<1>abc abc abc abc</1>
<1>a</1>
<1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</1><2>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</2><3>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</3>
<1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</1><2>adipiscing elit. Duis vehicula, quam non</2><3>lobortis molestie, purus dui porta sed.</3>
```

I leave it to you to figure out how to shred the (pseudo xml) string into your target columns which depends how repeatable the solution needs to be.  If it's a one off - stick the output from my function into a temporary cargo column in your output table and then fashion update statements to pull each block out, one by one, into the desired output column.  If you need to repeat this often, write an SP that creates a temp table and cursors through it and moves the blocks out into the target columns all at the same time.  You could, obviously, rip my code apart and use the logic directly to fashion a dynamic update statement (adding a SET <targetfield> to <block value> as each block is snipped out of the input string) to be executed at the end of each enumeration.

I leave it to you to decide how to proceed (even if that is to ask a more direct question, giving an idea which way you would like to proceed).